# Can I transfer a Oracle VM VirtualBox Ubuntu Image generated on Windows to a Mac?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VM via Oracle VM Virtual Box running Ubuntu on Windows - can I transfer that image to a Virtual Box version installed on a Mac or is that incompatible?

Comment: Have you tried transferring the VM?

Comment: I currently don't own a Mac but was considering switching. Hence the question.

Comment: Yes; VirtualBox VMs are platform independent.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VirutalBox software should be able to run the VM regardless of the operating system it itself is running on.

Having said that, if your VM relies on any passthrough devices, you should make sure they are present in the machine you're transferring the VM to.